# Share to teams implementation in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to implement `share to teams` functionality identical to the one provided in outlook. I have done some implementation referring to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-web-apps).

However, the message character limit is 200 characters. Is there any way I could overcome this limitation or even another approach which I can use to implement the same functionality?
Thanks.